# Ошибка при запуске Qt-приложения с кириллицей в пути

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, cx-freeze

PyQt5-приложение, собрано в exe через Cx_freeze. Запускается на системе без Python-среды и т.д. Если в пути нахождения exe-шника есть кириллица, то выводит ошибку "This application failed to start vecause no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the appplication may fix this problem".
Как научить видеть библиотеку при кириллице в пути?

Comment: Скопировать из lib/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/ папки platforms и styles (если необходимо) в корень к exe-шнику помогает, но хотелось бы понять, как без копирования можно указать библиотеки при кириллице в пути

Comment: Скорее всего, `Cx_freeze` не нашел сам те библиотеки, поэтому ему нужно было их руками указать (типа такого https://github.com/gil9red/dev_window/blob/727bd18e7935f095cf3be4d5e24d812452e4c3f8/setup.py#L12). И эта ошибка никак не относится проблемой кириллицы в пути, т.к. проблема в отсутствии необходимых либ, поправьте вопрос

Comment: @gil9red все библиотеки cx_freeze находит. Это уже собранный exe с lib со всеми нужными библиотеками. Отлично запускается только с латиницей в пути. Стоит только переименовать в пути ранее папку в кириллицу - ошибка.

Comment: А при сборке не было логов с папкой `platforms`? Типа: `copying C:/users/ipetrash/anaconda3/lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll -> D:\dist\platforms\qwindows.dll`. Возможно, кириллица и повлияла на это, но это не запуск приложения :)

Comment: @gil9red сборка в англоязычной среде проводилась

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл обходной вариант решения. Скопировать из lib/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/ папки platforms и styles (если необходимо) в корень к exe-шнику.